# Reloading relevant results only after CRUD request completed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm developing a CRUD app for a company to keep track of its employees. The content must refresh after a CRUD operation has been completed ie. when an employee has been added the employee results must update, but the entire page must not reload. I've tried using the $('#employee-results').load('php/getAll.php'); etc but this just dumps the whole response text in the div when I need to use the response to reload the content like its shown when employee data is retrieved on page load below:

```
function getEmployeeData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "php/getAll.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      let employees = data.data;
      
      currentData = employees;

      employees.forEach(function(position){

        $("#employee-results").append(`<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-user fa-xl"></i><h5 class="card-title record"><span id="first-name-${position.id}">${position.firstName}</span>&nbsp<span id="last-name-${position.id}">${position.lastName}</span></h5></div>
            <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-id-badge"></i><h6 id="employee-id-${position.id}" class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted record">${position.id}</h6></div>
            <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-at"></i><p id="email-${position.id}">${position.email}<p></div>
            <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i><p id="jobTitle-${position.id}">${position.jobTitle}<p></div>
            <p id="department-id-${position.id}" class="department-id">${position.departmentID}</p>
            <div class="dept-location"><div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-building"></i><h6 class="record" id="department-${position.id}">${position.department}</h5></div>
            <div class="individual-result"><i class="fa-solid fa-map-location"></i><h6 class="record" id="location-${position.id}">${position.location}</h5></div>
            
          </div>
          <button id="${position.id}" class="edit-employee-button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editEmployeeModal" onclick="populateEditModalWithCurrentInfo(this.id);"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>`);
    
      })
    }
  })
}
```

I'm sure I am close with the jQuery .load() method but I'm not sure how I harness it to achieve what is needed.

Comment: you need to empty the div before looping: `$("#employee-results").html('')`

Comment: If the problem is page reload?? So the provided code is not the reason .. The problem will be in the event handler which you need to provide .. And show how you call/run this `getEmployeeData` function